# Why python can not run wget?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, wget

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
import os 
import wget

PATH = "/Users/kaikeichan/Downloads/chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/")

username = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME,"username"))
)

password = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME,"password"))
)

login = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="loginForm"]/div/div[3]')

username.clear()
password.clear()

username.send_keys('learntocodeztm')
password.send_keys('929kai927')
login.click()


search = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="react-root"]/section/nav/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/input'))
)

keyword = "#cat"
search.send_keys(keyword)
time.sleep(1)
search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
time.sleep(1)
search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME,"FFVAD"))
)

imgs = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("FFVAD")

path = os.path.join(keyword)
os.mkdir(path)

count = 0
for img in imgs:
    save_as = os.path.join(path, keyword + str(count) + '.jpg')
    # print(img.get_attribute("src"))
    wget.download(img.get_attribute("src"), save_as)
    count += 1
```

```sh
terminal error message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 1350, in do_open
    h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1240, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1286, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1235, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1006, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 946, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1409, in connect
    self.sock = self._context.wrap_socket(self.sock,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 500, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 1040, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 1309, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1108)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ig.py", line 57, in <module>
    wget.download(img.get_attribute("src"), save_as)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wget.py", line 526, in download
    (tmpfile, headers) = ulib.urlretrieve(binurl, tmpfile, callback)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 247, in urlretrieve
    with contextlib.closing(urlopen(url, data)) as fp:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 222, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 525, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 542, in _open
    result = self._call_chain(self.handle_open, protocol, protocol +
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 502, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 1393, in https_open
    return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPSConnection, req,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 1353, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1108)
```

Comment: Try adding your code inside trip " ` ", that'll make it more understandable.

Answer (score 0):

> Why python can not run wget?

Your traceback clearly shows that there is some problem with SSL certificate

```
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1108)
```

and

```
<urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1108)
```

You are using `wget.download` function from [`wget`](https://pypi.org/project/wget/) which as far as I know does not offer easy way to turn off verification.